Why is velocity proportional to radius in a spherical explosion?
While doing problems on spherically symmetric explosions, I noticed I had been intuitively assuming that velocity scales linearly with radius of the "shell" under consideration. To be more concrete, take the following problem;

Consider a spherical homogeneous cloud of mass $M$ made by an explosion. Due to energy received form the explosion, it is expanding and the expansion is spherically symmetric. At an instant its radius is $R_0$ and the particles on the surface are moving away from its center with velocity $V_0$. Its radius when expansions ceases is given by $\frac{nGMR_0}{2GM-R_0V_0^2}$. Find $n$.

In the solution given, it is assumed that particles at a distance $r$ having velocity $v$ obey $v/r=V_0/R_o$ without any explanation. Intuitively, it makes sense but I'm unable to find any scaling argument to formally justify this assumption. Can anyone help me?

It is not a shell but a homogeneous cloud.

Have you learned about Sedov's blast wave solution?

I have not, but I will immediately check it out

The assumption is that of uniform expansion at the instant of explosion.

Could you please elaborate a little? How does one define uniform expansion? Does it mean that the density of the homogeneous cloud is decreasing linearly?

@Cognoscenti With the 3d power.
